# How to divide street address into 3 lines with label for each line and update them in checkout form for billing address

Tags: magento2, checkout, billing-address

I have referred to below solution for dividing the street address into 3 lines.

[For shipping form in checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187796/how-to-add-label-on-all-lines-of-street-fields-in-checkout-and-turn-then-require.) .

I have made changes for billing address below referring the above link.

```
   <?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']
            ['children']['street'] = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
                'required' => false, //turn false because I removed main label
                'dataScope' => 'billing-address-form.street',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'sortOrder' => 52,
                'type' => 'group',
                'additionalClasses' => 'street',
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'label' => __('Flat, House no., Building, Company, Apartment: '),
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                        'config' => [
                            'customScope' => 'billing-address-form.street',
                            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                        ],
                        'dataScope' => '0',
                        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                        'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 255],
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __('Area, Colony, Street, Sector, Village: '),
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                        'config' => [
                            'customScope' => 'billing-address-form.street',
                            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                        ],
                        'dataScope' => '1',
                        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                        'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 255],
                    ],
                    [
                        'label' => __('Landmark e.g. near apollo hospital: '),
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                        'config' => [
                            'customScope' => 'billing-address-form.street',
                            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                        ],
                        'dataScope' => '2',
                        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                        'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 255],
                    ],
                ]
            ];
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

The street field gets divided into three lines with label for each but when saved the fields are not getting saved.

How can I make this working for Billing address in checkout.

Answer (score 3):

> Create Plugin via di.xml Under : VendorName\ModuleName\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger">
      <plugin name="shippingAddress" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger\Plugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Create Plugin File  Under :
>   VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger\Plugin.php

```
<?php 
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger;

class Plugin
{
  public function afterMerge(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger $subject, $result)
  {
    if (array_key_exists('street', $result)) {
      $result['street']['children'][0]['label'] = __('Street Address Line 1');
       $result['street']['children'][1]['label'] = __('Street Address line 2');
       $result['street']['children'][2]['label'] = __('Street Address line 3');

    }
    return $result;
  }
}
```

Comment: With the help of this you will get labels in both Shipping as well as billing address forms.

Comment: Thanks nauman for the revert..I am getting the labels but the issue is when saved the street address in not getting saved in billing address

Comment: Do you want to save labels too?

Comment: No,the data in the address fields is to saved

Comment: I have provided the link in the question which i posted through which I am getting the labels in both shipping and billing(have used billing address form layout components). But in shipping address form the address fields are getting saved but not in billing address

Comment: oh ok try to see in inspect element. the label tag may be there. But due to CSS it not visible,
select <Label> Tag & add css position: unset; via inspect element.
If it visible then contact your design team to make change it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87447/discussion-between-user3313626-and-nauman-m-mansuri).

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, street line is divided into 3 different address lines with label for each line, but after adding data and update, it shows blank spaces.

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Plugin class vendor\presso\checkout\block\Checkout\AttributeMerger\Plugin doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

This example will change the labels on the payment page for all the payment/billing forms (moneris, stripe, braintree etc.).

I'm posting an example of how to change **street** field labels on the payment page. But you can target any field by replacing the `[street]` value.

Please, if this is not the best practice let me know. I didn't manage to find many examples or documentation about this, so I kind of did this myself.

`app/code/Vendor/Checkout/Plugin/LayoutProccessorPluginPayment.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Checkout\Plugin;

class LayoutProccessorPluginPayment
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array                                            $jsLayout
     *
     * @return array
     */

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array                                            $jsLayout
    ) {
        $paymentForms = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']
                        ['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']
                        ['payments-list']['children'];

        // Change billing field labels for every payment method
        foreach ($paymentForms as $paymentMethodForm => $paymentMethodValue) {

            $paymentMethodCode = str_replace('-form', '', $paymentMethodForm);

            //Checks if billing step available.
            if (!isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymentMethodCode . '-form'])) {
                continue;
            }
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']
            ['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']
            ['payments-list']['children'][$paymentMethodCode . '-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['street'] = [
                'component'         => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
                'label'             => __('Street Address'),
                'required'          => false,
                'dataScope'         => 'billingAddress.street',
                'provider'          => 'checkoutProvider',
                'sortOrder'         => 50,
                'type'              => 'group',
                'additionalClasses' => 'street',
                'children'          => [
                    [
                        'label'      => __('Label1'),
                        'component'  => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                        'config'     => [
                            'customScope' => 'billingAddress',
                            'template'    => 'ui/form/field',
                            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                        ],
                        'dataScope'  => '0',
                        'provider'   => 'checkoutProvider',
                        'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "min_text_length" => 1],
                    ],
                    [
                        'label'      => __('Label2'),
                        'component'  => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                        'config'     => [
                            'customScope' => 'billingAddress',
                            'template'    => 'ui/form/field',
                            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                        ],
                        'dataScope'  => '1',
                        'provider'   => 'checkoutProvider',
                        'validation' => ['required-entry' => false, "min_text_length" => 1],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

And then add the plugin in `app/code/Vendor/Checkout/etc/di.xml`

```
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="billing-street-labels" type="Vendor\Checkout\Plugin\LayoutProccessorPluginPayment" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
```