# How to add label to street fields in Customer registration in admin panel?

Tags: magento2, overrides, admin-panel, customer-address, street-address

[image]

I want to add two more Labels Colony and Area after Street Address.How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I created a module for this issue, if anyone have interest. https://packagist.org/packages/i9/streetlabel

Answer (score 0):

I assume the 3 fields are address fields and you want to add labels on fields 2 and 3.
If so, you can achieve this via a layout processor.

First declare your layout processor.
Add this in one of your custom modules in `etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="layoutProcessors" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add-street-labels" xsi:type="object">[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\LayoutProcessor</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Now create the layout processor `[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/LayoutProcessor.php`

```
<?php

namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Block;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;

class LayoutProcessor implements LayoutProcessorInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayManager
     */
    private $arrayManager;

    /**
     * LayoutProcessor constructor.
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     */
    public function __construct(ArrayManager $arrayManager) 
    {
         $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }    

    /**
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function process($jsLayout)
    {
        return $this->modifyAddressLabels($jsLayout);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    private function modifyAddressLabels($jsLayout)
    {
        //layout path of the street component
        $path = 'components/checkout/children/steps/children/shipping-step/children/shippingAddress/children/';
        $path .= 'shipping-address-fieldset/children/street/children';
        $line1Path = $path . '/1'; //line with index 1 (second field has index 1 because arrays start at 0)
        $line1 = $this->arrayManager->get($line1Path, $jsLayout); 
        if ($line1) {
            $line1['label'] = __('Colony');
            $jsLayout = $this->arrayManager->set($line1Path, $jsLayout, $line1);
        }

        $line2Path = $path . '/2'; //line with index 2
        $line2 = $this->arrayManager->get($line2Path, $jsLayout); 
        if ($line2) {
            $line2['label'] = __('Area');
            $jsLayout = $this->arrayManager->set($line2Path, $jsLayout, $line2);
        }
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

You can even skip the `modifyAddressLabels` method and implement everything in `process` methods. I did it like this in case you need to add other changes to the layout and you want to keep them separate.
Untested code so watch out for typos.

Comment: Thanks For the answer. I tried it but didn't work. Also I want this for Customer->Add New Customer->Address.